# Cannot log in after successful password change

Tags: 16.04, sudo, password

I can change the password of my newly created user, but I cannot then log in.

```
stephane@vps331749:~$ sudo passwd alaoutid
Enter new UNIX password: 
Retype new UNIX password: 
passwd: password updated successfully
stephane@vps331749:~$ su alaoutid
Password: 
su: Authentication failure
```

Same thing if changing the root password.

```
stephane@vps331749:~$ sudo passwd root
Enter new UNIX password: 
Retype new UNIX password: 
passwd: password updated successfully
stephane@vps331749:~$ su
Password: 
su: Authentication failure
```

I'm a sudoer.

EDIT: The user shell is:

```
stephane@vps331749:~$ cat /etc/passwd | grep alaoutid
alaoutid:x:1002:1003::/home/alaoutid:/bin/bash

stephane@vps331749:~$ su -s /bin/bash alaoutid
Password: 
su: Authentication failure
```

EDIT: I could become `alaoutid` with this two steps:

```
stephane@vps331749:~$ sudo bash
[sudo] password for stephane: 
root@vps331749:~# su - alaoutid
alaoutid@vps331749:~$
```

EDIT: I could become `root` with this two steps:

```
stephane@vps331749:~$ sudo bash
root@vps331749:~# su - root
root@vps331749:~#
```

EDIT: Some configuration files if it can help

```
sudo cat /etc/pam.d/common-account
account [success=1 new_authtok_reqd=done default=ignore]    pam_unix.so 
account requisite           pam_deny.so
account required            pam_permit.so

sudo cat /etc/pam.d/common-auth
auth    [success=1 default=ignore]  pam_unix.so nullok_secure
auth    requisite           pam_deny.so
auth    required            pam_permit.so

sudo cat /etc/nsswitch.conf | egrep "passwd|group|shadow"
passwd:         compat
group:          compat
shadow:         compat
gshadow:        files
netgroup:       nis
```

The `alaoutid` user is known:

```
id alaoutid
uid=1003(alaoutid) gid=1004(alaoutid) groups=1004(alaoutid),27(sudo),1001(dev)
```

The `root` user is known:

```
id root
uid=0(root) gid=0(root) groups=0(root)
```

Comment: what happened when you execute `su -s /bin/bash adil` ?

Comment: I added an edit to the question.

Comment: what happened when you run `sudo bash`, and as `root, you are running `su -  adil`?

Comment: It becomes `adil` then. I added an EDIT in the question.

Comment: okay... the `su` from `root` doesn't check for password.... can you try and set very simple password for user adil, e.g. `0000`, and then try execute `su - adil` from your regular user account? (I'd like to make sure that it is not a keyboard problem)

Comment: I just did it `stephane@vps331749:~$ sudo passwd adil
[sudo] password for stephane: 
Enter new UNIX password: 
Retype new UNIX password: 
passwd: password updated successfully
stephane@vps331749:~$ su - adil
Password: 
su: Authentication failure
stephane@vps331749:~$ ` and it failed to log in. I have no known issue with my personal keyboard.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/55683/discussion-between-yaron-and-stephane).

Comment: The same thing happens for the `root` user. I can change its password. But then it refuses the login at the `su` command, saying `su: Authentication failure`.

Comment: after setting a password for a regular user, can you login to that account using the regular login prompt?

Comment: @Yaron It is a remote server, so no, I cannot.

Comment: Can't you try to login to the other account using the same method you are using for login into your account?

Comment: I indeed could become `root` using this method, first with a `sudo bash` command and then with a `su - root` command. I updated my questing to reflect it.